# Which waveform for photic stimulation should be used to generate SSVEP in a narrow band around desired frequency

Tags: neuroscience, vision, optical-illusion, stimulation

I am trying to build my own flickering light stimulation device. The light source will be a COB Red LED cluster (~627nm) (like one of [these](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1812498.pdf)) with brightness controlled using Pulse Width Modulation through an Arduino.

[This article](https://www.shift.is/2017/10/ultimate-guide-brainwave-entrainment/) mentions that using a square wave to drive the light source leads to harmonics in the SSVEP. This suggests that I should use a waveform that is close to sinusoidal.

Considering the [luminous efficiency function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_efficiency_function) of the human eye how should I modify this waveform so that the subjective "brightness" perceived by the generalized human eye is sinusoidal?

If this question is not sufficiently focused, please advise in the comments and I will edit accordingly.